# Xamarin.Forms - Use XAML element as a parameter

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

In my XAML page I have set a Picker. It works good, but it's not very user-friendly, sice there's no possibility to add an arrow icon in the Picker parameters. So I added an Image with a Gesture Recognizer, like this :

```
<Grid HeightRequest="50">
    <Picker x:Name="mySlugPicker" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Title="Sélectionnez votre serveur" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerList}"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" TextColor="Black" TitleColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="4" Source="down_arrow.png">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding OpenPicker}" CommandParameter="{Binding mySlugPicker}"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

All I want to do is open the Picker when the down arrow is pressed, so I defined a Command in my ViewModel like that :

```
public Command<Picker> OpenPicker { get; }

public ViewModel()
{
    OpenPicker = new Command<Picker>(TriggerPickerOpening);
}

private void TriggerPickerOpening(Picker picker)
{
    picker.Focus();
}
```

As you can see, I defined the "x:Name" property for my Picker, and I passed this x:Name as my command parameter. But when I'm launching my app, it throws me a NullReferenceException.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By not specifying a `Source` to your binding, it will go to search for  `mySlugPicker` in your page BindingContext which is your view model and where `mySlugPicker` does not exist:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="50">
    <Picker x:Name="mySlugPicker" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  Title="Sélectionnez votre serveur" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerList}"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" TextColor="Black" TitleColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White"/>
    <Image Grid.Column="4" Source="down_arrow.png">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding OpenPicker}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySlugPicker}}"/>
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

A good practice to avoid exception/crash would be to do a null check (don't trust parameter) before calling a method:

```
private void TriggerPickerOpening(Picker picker)
{
    picker?.Focus();
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
private void TriggerPickerOpening(Picker picker)
{
    if (picker != null)
        picker.Focus();
}
```

[Null-Coditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow didn't noticed me your answer ^^
Yes, it works ! So the "Source" was the missing element ^^ Thank you! :)